# Pq quando eu defino uma constante B = constante A e altero uma das propriedades da constante B a propriedade da constante A também é modificada?

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
const a = new Map();

const construct = {
    nome: 'Nome',
    alguma: 'coisa'
}

a.set('Chave', construct);

const b = a.get('Chave');

b.alguma = 'outraCoisa'

console.log(a) // Mostra Map(1) { 'Chave' => { nome: 'Nome', alguma: 'outraCoisa' } }
```

Não tem um problema exatamente, mas não sei o por que disso acontecer e também não sei o termo certo pra pesquisar no google e entender melhor, então se alguem puder me dar uma explicação breve ficaria muito grato

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso acontece porque `a` está apontando para um objeto, mas não é o objeto em si, é só uma referência para ele, como um endereço residencial é em relação a uma residência. Quando você faz por exemplo `b = a` faz essas duas referências apontarem para o mesmo objeto e portanto tudo que você modifica no objeto através de uma dessas referências se reflete na hora de acessar o objeto pela outra.

Isso é indireção e acesso a um objeto através da sua referência.

Por isso ainda acho importante conhecer C, que dá o conceito de ponteiros, que não se acha nessas linguagens mais na moda, e são basicamente referências porém mais baixo nível, sem abstrair demais o conceito para não dar a impressão que o objeto e a referência são a mesma coisa.